# How to run a query string as SQL in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I have a query in a variable and I want to run it :

```
    $sql = "select  id,
                title,
                parent_id 
        from    (select * from categories
                 order by parent_cat_id, id) base,
                (select @pv := '$category_id') tmp
        where   find_in_set(parent_cat_id, @pv) > 0
        and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)";
```

How can run it as a query ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the query using the `DB::select` function:

```
$categories = DB::select($sql);
dd($categories);
```